# Sorting on number field db4o Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, db4o

I am using **db4o** database for storing data in my Android application. I want to sort objects on **Number** field.

But, when I use `query.descend("number").orderDescending();`, I am getting `NullPointerException`.

Why?

Comment: if its giving null pointer exception that means it is not getting the view

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not getting the view"?

Comment: in short the pointer is not actually pointing at the NUMBER field. show us the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, solved problem.

Actually the problem was number was stored in format double exponential. Then I converted the number in long and the problem is gone :-)